# isNaN gets different result in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to bind the `onclick` function in each link of a web page, so I use this function:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');// total 5 links
for(var key in links){
   //always be true in IE, But just be true from second latest in chrome
   alert(isNaN(parseInt(key)));
   if(isNaN(parseInt(key))){
      break;
   }else{
      ...
   }
}
```

Please help.

Update:
It seems is the problem of `for (var key in links)`, when is in IE, the `key` become the Id of the link, but it's just number in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enumerating other stuff beyond your anchor tags, and some of this stuff is supposed to be `NaN`. Use a regular `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    // do something with links[i], 
    // which is guaranteed to be
    // an anchor tag
}
```

Comment: thank you bfavaretto, I found the problem is in for(key in) statement.

Comment: Exactly. `for..in` will loop through other properties of `links`, such as `item` (which is `NaN`).

Comment: yeah, you re right, but in ie since I cannot use links[key].addEventListener('click',function(){}) also. It will throw an error exception

Comment: That's a different issue, you have to check before using addEventListener, and use attachEvent if it's not available (ie<9).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery (and I strongly recommend you do) use the `$.isNumeric()` function.

You should also replace the `document.getElementsByTagName` with a jQuery selector like this

```
$('a').each(function(index, tag) {
    if($.isNumeric($(tag.attr('SOMEATTRIBUTE'))) {
        // do whatever you want here
    } else {
        // do the other condition here
    }
});
```